# How do answers leave the low-qual review queue?

Tags: feature-request, review, low-quality-posts

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19414995/131433 turned up in the history. It got some 'recommend deletion' from people with no delete privs, but was not shown to me (or anyone else with actual delete privs). It would make sense for answers in the low-qual queue to hang around looking for actual delete votes.

Answer (score 1):

Four people recommended deletion of that item.  It was still in the queue.  A 5th reccomended deletion would have deleted it, but 3 users with delete privs deleted it outside of the queue before that could happen.

Comment: So howcome the queue didn't show it to me? The queue told me there was nothing for me to review, so I looked at the history in an idle moment, and that's how I found it.

Comment: @Rosinante The review was invalidated because it was already deleted outside of review. There's no reason to continue reviewing it at that point.

Comment: No, that hadn't happened yet. I was the first one to cast an actual delete vote.

Comment: @Rosinante My guess is someone else was in the process of reviewing it at that point in time.  It doesn't show the same post to multiple people concurrently to avoid race conditions.